# How can I automate the generation of dependabot configuration files for many repositories

Tags: github, dependabot, dependabot-script

I need to configure `dependabot` for a large number of repos (manually configuring will take days  ).

Some repos are "single language" such as `typescript` using a single `package.json` `package-ecosystem: npm` while other repositories are styled as "mono repos" and use a variety of languages and accompanying package managers with different nestings.

As the `dependabot.yml` file needs to be configured with the appropriate root and package ecosystem, I can not re-use a simple config file and expect it to work for all.

I am scripting this, but cloning so many repositories are slow and error-prone.

An example of a "complex" `dependabot` config file looks like this:

```
version: 2
updates:
- package-ecosystem: cargo
  directory: "/package/a"
  schedule:
    interval: daily
- package-ecosystem: cargo
  directory: "/package/b"
  schedule:
    interval: daily
- package-ecosystem: cargo
  directory: "/package/c"
  schedule:
    interval: daily
- package-ecosystem: cargo
  directory: "/package/a"
  schedule:
    interval: daily
- package-ecosystem: npm
  directory: "/sites/a"
  schedule:
    interval: daily
- package-ecosystem: npm
  directory: "/sites/b"
  schedule:
    interval: daily
... 20 other roots
```

I would hope for an option such as the following:

```
- package-ecosystem: npm
  directory: "/sites/*" <<<<< some wild card / pattern matching here?
  schedule:
    interval: daily
- package-ecosystem: cargo
  directory: "/package/*"
  schedule:
    interval: daily
```

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Dependabot is not currently capabale of wildcards, but it has been [a long requested feature in the `dependabot-core` repository](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/2178).

Some kind people built automation that can generate a `dependabot.yml` file based on your wildcards and the files in your repository. For example check [the Action by Makeshift on GitHub](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/2178#issuecomment-1321161917).